# Upload only modified files to server?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

How to upload only modified files to server? I tried  to upload it manually. But it is not comfortable.

I tried to use git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what PhpStorm does by default.

Please set "Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment | Options | Upload changed files automatically to the default server" to "On explicit save action".

Next time you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, only changed files will be uploaded.